# Unable to run the .apk on x86_64

Tags: android, react-native, x86, x86-64

I have an app built with react-native 0.52.0. After receiving notification from google, I am trying make it supportable for 64bit as well.

So I tried adding these

```
ndk {
       abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
```

But I was getting,

```
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/my.com.app/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit"
```

[So I tried analysing the apk file, and I got to know the .so files inside x86 and x86_64 are not same. Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjlDy.png)

How can I overcome this ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to upgrade RN to 0.59 for 64bit support. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732351/64-bit-version-issue-in-react-native-android-app-by-google-play-store

Comment: Please note, the upgrade process from lower RN to 0.59 is a bit tricky. Might help to follow [instructions provided in release notes](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/03/12/releasing-react-native-059#upgrading-to-059).

Comment: Are you trying to make separate Apk for each architecture ?

Comment: @Amar, oh okay. thank you. I will try upgrading the RN.